# How can I set new RealmConfiguration when I do RealmMigration on android?

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-migration

I am trying to migrate my data from realm to a new Encrypted realm database.
 Untill now I have been able to check some codes to do the Migration:

```
private void setRealmConfiguration() {
        realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.
                Builder().
                schemaVersion(1).
                migration(new MyMigration()).
                build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }
```

And this is my migration class:

```
public class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {
    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
        byte[] key = new byte[64];
        new SecureRandom(key);


        if (oldVersion == 0) {

            realm.writeEncryptedCopyTo(new File("/data/data/com.project.test.realm/files/encrypted.realm"), key);

        }

    }
}
```

From what I read new configuration should be setted inside Migration class but I haven't find the way.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand what is the "new configuration" you are talking about ?

Comment: @Maelig I want to set new configuration for my realm database inside my migration class but I don't know how to do it

Comment: You mean set the RealmConfiguration of your `encrypted.realm` ? Why would you do that ?

Comment: My actual realm configuration is not encrypted, that is why I migrated data to my encrypted realm DB and now I want to set encrypted.realm as my default realm DB whenever I launch my app.

Comment: I guess you need to create 2 configurations in your `setRealmConfiguration()` and you'll remove the old one on the next release, because the migration is done once, you cannot set everytime your new Realm configuration in migration